# Multi dimensional list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have 9 role and 10 Environments and I need to give access Readwrite/Read access to Role based on environment and i have data structure/set as below,

```
ROLE  Environment    Access
A    one            ReadWrite
     two            Readwite
     three          Read
     four          Read
    five           Read
    six            Read
    seven          Read
    eight          Read
    Nine           Read
    ten            Read
B   one            Readwrite
    two            Read
    three          Readwrite
    four           Readwrite
    five           Readwrite
    six            Readwrite
    seven          Readwrite
    eight          Readwrite
    Nine           Read
    ten           Read
C   one           Readwrite
    two           Read
    three        Readwrite
    four         Readwrite
    five         Readwrite
    six         Readwrite
    seven       Read
    eight      Readwrite
    Nine       Read
    ten        Read
D   one       Readwrite
    two       Read
    three     Readwrite
    four      Read
    five      Readwrite
    six       Readwrite
    seven     ReadWrite
    eight     Read
    Nine      Read
    ten       Read
```

I want to give Readwrite/Read access based on  above data list for example ROLE **A** Environment **One** should get readdwrite Access

How can we do it in Ansible?

**Note:**

1. To give Access , we call Rest API via Ansible URI module
2. I have mentioned  4 role but i have 9 Role

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need some clarification... How is your inventory organized? Is it something in the lines of: `[role_name] Host1...`? (I tried to add a multiline comment but... that's not currently supported...

Comment: sorry i understood , i have given a few information , I am trying to on board AD group in vault

Comment: you're trying to add these role variables to the vault? why don't you use [more than one vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/vault.html#id10)?

Comment: Ok thank you,i will look into it

Comment: If you need anything, please ask, I am at your disposal

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your list is... well, a list. Take a look at the documentation for [nested loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id9):

```yaml
- name: Give users access to multiple databases
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    name: "{{ item[0] }}"
    priv: "{{ item[1] }}.*:ALL"
    append_privs: yes
    password: "foo"
  loop: "{{ ['alice', 'bob'] |product(['clientdb', 'employeedb', 'providerdb'])|list }}"
```

Also take a look at [this section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id30) for more information on nested loops.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used Netsed loop but i stuck with When Condition how to print/ disaply read/write access